# sh: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected from chgrp -R 0 <app/csv> &&

Tags: docker, shell

I am trying to run following docker, but getting the error `/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "&&" unexpected`. Its coming from the last **&&** when i try to run chgrp

Here is my docker file.

```
# The builder from node image
FROM node:14.5.0-buster as swi
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

# Move our files into directory name "app"
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN cd /app && npm install
COPY . /app
RUN cd /app && npm run build
RUN chgrp -R 0 <app/csv> && \
    chmod -R g=u <app/csv>
EXPOSE 5001

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Tried removing **&&** as \ means run next command but getting the same error

Comment: Are the angle brackets only for the code sample or are they in the actual code? If they are in the actual code: could you try to remove them? --- Have you tried to remove the linebreak and the backslash all together?

Comment: Thanks, I already tried removing linebreak and backlash.

Comment: The issue was the angle brackets. yes it was a placeholder. Thankyou for spotting that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the angle brackets from the paths. Furthermore, since the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) is set to `/app`, we can just `chgroup` and `chown` the folder `csv`. I would also suggest to remove the linebreak and wirte it as one-liner:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 csv && chmod -R g=u csv
```

We can simplify the docker file overall by using the fact that the `WORKDIR` is set to `/app`:

```
# The builder from node image
FROM node:14.5.0-buster as swi
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

# Move our files into directory name "app"
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
RUN chgrp -R 0 csv && chmod -R g=u csv
EXPOSE 5001

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The angle brackets are wrong - you should just use the directory name as-is:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 app/csv && \
    chmod -R g=u app/csv
```

Comment: also i added slash infront of app or it was not able to find the folder /app/csv